# Laravel Eloquent Relationships between multiple tables

Tags: php, laravel

Im researching laravel relationships, but i can only see them between 2 tables ... Im wondering if there is such a thing as a one-to-one that works with 3 tables?

For instance, i have the following tables

```
websites
preferences
websites_preferences
```

One website has one preferences, but through the websites_preferences table is where the relationship is.

Any help would be great.

Cheers,

Comment: It looks like a [Many-to-Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship to me.

Comment: In one to one you don't require the websites_preferences table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use the intermediate table for One-to-one relationship.

If you want to use Many-to-many relationship between websites and preferences, You can do like the following.

For this you need the intermediate table 'website_preferences'

```
class Website extends Model
{
    public function preferences()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Preference', 'website_preferences', 'website_id', 'preference_id');
    }
}

class Preference extends Model
{
    public function websites()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Website', 'website_preferences', 'preference_id', 'website_id');
    }
}
```

Refer this link, it might be helpful
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Answer (score 2):

You don't need websites_preferences table if you only want one-to-one relationship.

But you can do this -> Has Many Through relationship:

```
class Website extends Model

    {
        public function preferences()
        {
            return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Preferences', 'App\Website_preferences');
        }
    }
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: This seems to be what im after ... Will this associate the specific preference with the website through the website_preferences table? ... Would this be the best way to approach the table structure

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need a third table for one-to-one relationship. Third table is for many-to-many. You can use `primary key` of `preferences` table as foreign key of `websites` table.